# JxBrowser does not refresh

Tags: caching, jxbrowser

I am currently using JxBrowser as an embedded browser in my Java application. I create a browser like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Browser browser = new Browser();
BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(700, 500);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);

browser.loadURL("https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph");
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        browser.getCacheStorage().clearCache();
        browser.loadURL("https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
}
```

When the first URL is opened, I sign in and choose to not keep me signed in. I then close that window and when the second window opens, I see that my user is still logged in. As you can see I am clearing cache as well before opening the  URL the second time. But the cache is not cleared.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with Google Chrome? What happens if you choose to not keep you signed in in one tab, then close it and load this URL in another tab? I suppose you will get the same behavior. Please let us know.

Comment: I tried the same with google chrome. I just have this URL opened in google chrome, I signed in and chose not to keep me signed in and closed the window. Then opened google chrome again and I am not signed in. My user credentials do not remain.

Comment: When you close the window, you close the whole application. Please run Google Chrome, open 2 empty tabs, load in one tab the required URL, choose to not keep you signed in in the tab, then close it and load this URL in another tab. Do not close the window.

Comment: I tried with the tabs and the user credentials remain. If we do not want to keep the user credentials, do you recommend disposing the browser and creating a new instance each time? I am asking because I see on teamdev site that multi browser instances with shared cache do not work well. Is that true? If so please let me know if there are other ways to achieve this. I see "ERROR:password_manager.cpp(154)] NOT IMPLEMENTED" error in console during the sign in process. Not sure if this is related to this issue.

Comment: If you see the same behavior in Google Chrome, then this is probably how it's designed. I think disposing and creating a new Browser instance should help, but only if you use one Browser instance in your application. If you create multiple Browser instances, then it will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the issue is related to caching. Would you please create a simple sample that can be used for reproducing the issue from my end?

Comment: I edited my description to include the sample and updated problem

Comment: Thank you, I've tested it with Google Chrome from my side as suggested above, using a third-party web-application and the behavior is the same. I suppose "not to keep signed in" option works only if you close the browser completely, not the tab or window.